# boolean expression must not be empty error in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to check if the user likes the current post and set an icon. I'm trying to do a simple check but it throws an error.

The method I created

```
List<String> fav = List<String>();

checkFav(String id) {
    bool isFav = fav.contains(id);

    if(isFav)
      return true;
    else
      return null;
  }
```

And where I use the method

```
IconButton(
           icon: Icon(favorite.checkFav(widget.blogModel.id)
               ? Icons.favorite
               : Icons.favorite_border,
                 color: Colors.redAccent),

                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(
                        () {
                          favorite.checkFav(widget.blogModel.id)
                              ? favorite.deleteItemToFav(widget.blogModel.id)
                              : favorite.addItemToFav(widget.blogModel.id);
                        },
                      );
                      //favorite.checkItemInFav(widget.blogModel.id, context);
                    },
                  ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `checkFav` should specify it returns `bool`. Also, you are returning `null` in case of `false` which is properly not what you have intended.

So you can rewrite your method to the following which will properly work:

```
bool checkFav(String id) => fav.contains(id);
```

Comment: Yes the error is gone but the icon still does not change

Comment: @SemihYılmaz Well, that is an entire different issue which is not even part of your question. Please make another question for that problem,

Answer (score 0):

Good day. Try this code:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final _favorites = <String>['1', '2', '3'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final buttonIsActive = checkFavorites('1', _favorites);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        body: Center(child: buildFavoriteButton(isActive: buttonIsActive)),
       ),
    );
  }
}

bool checkFavorites(String id, List<String> favorites) {
  return favorites.contains(id);
}

Widget buildFavoriteButton({bool isActive = false}) {
  return IconButton(
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.ac_unit,
      color: isActive ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
    ),
    onPressed: () {},
  );
}
```